# Access enum values using generics

Tags: android, kotlin

How can i access enum values using generics?

Here is my class:

```
abstract class BasePacket<E: Enum<E>> (enumClass: Class<E>) where E: BasePacketChunk  {
   val enumValues = /***How t get enumClass values***/
   
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to make the question clearer.

Comment: Since you don't know at compile time what `E` is, you can obviously not access the enum constants. You can however access the methods available on all enums.

Comment: Assuming that `enumClass` is a `java.lang.Class` then you might be able to use [`Class#getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()).